# I get Identity insert error, when identity insert is set to on

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I got this error. I have table 'game'.in the game table I have only one identity column id. when I change Only Order Value, which is int and not identity, I always get this error.For example, I want to remove object from database and add another:

```
public ActionResult Position(int ID)
{
    var gg = db.games.Find(ID);
    db.games.Remove(db.games.Find(ID));
    gg.OrderValue = 42;
    db.games.Add(gg);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Admin");
}
```

Comment: I think your Auto Indentity increment not set.

Comment: Try saving changes after removal and try `gg.ID= 0;` after removing.

Comment: add [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGenerationOption.Identity)] to the PK of games.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice for removing an object would be like :

```
var gg = db.games.Find(Id);
if(gg != null)
{
    db.games.Attach(gg);
    db.games.Remove(gg);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

I don't know your scenario but, wouldn't it better to update Row instead of removing and inserting again?

**Edit:**
Based on your comment the error is: "Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'game' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF"

This error happens when you trying to update a column which is defined Identity, which means it will be **Auto-Generated**. usually, only the Columns that their records need to be Unique are defined Auto-Generated.
Considering that this action could be harmful(**EF** also knows it's harmful) there is no straight way to enable **Identity_Insert** from EntityFramework.

But you can do either:
1- Enable Identity_Insert :

```
context.ExecuteStoreCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[MyUser] ON");
```

2- Remove Identity from this Columns.

Comment: Hello Mohamed. I want to update row but when I do this I get an error :Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'game' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.